# Create reponse object from the JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, grouping

I have tried all the possible way but no luck to create the required reponse object from the current reponse  object, Please help

**Following is my current response object so please help to create desired response object from the following array of object**

```
[
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-01-11",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 10,
                    "objective_id": 354,
                    "id": 10,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-11T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "testing 234546",
                    "description": "53w5",
                    "objective_name": "Deliver all projects on time and budget",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 6,
                    "objective_id": 354,
                    "id": 6,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-11T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Ensure all Project managers use the tools and templates provided",
                    "description": "Just for testing",
                    "objective_name": "Deliver all projects on time and budget",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 8,
                    "objective_id": 354,
                    "id": 8,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-11T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Testing item 3",
                    "description": "Test",
                    "objective_name": "Deliver all projects on time and budget",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-01-12",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 17,
                    "objective_id": 348,
                    "id": 22,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-12T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "tedtsd  sdfsf",
                    "description": "sdfsfsdd fsdfsd f",
                    "objective_name": "People Diversity",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-01-13",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 9,
                    "objective_id": 349,
                    "id": 9,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-13T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "testing 123456",
                    "description": "53w5",
                    "objective_name": "management",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 15,
                    "objective_id": 348,
                    "id": 20,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-13T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Testing date issue another",
                    "description": "This is test only",
                    "objective_name": "People Diversity",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-01-14",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 4,
                    "objective_id": 348,
                    "id": 4,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-14T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Ensure every hiring manager is made aware of the objective weekly",
                    "description": "Hiring managers have to ensure that they get diversity ratios in the correct order, they should get weekly reminders on this.",
                    "objective_name": "People Diversity",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-01-21",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 27,
                    "objective_id": 344,
                    "id": 33,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-21T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Testing on 1/22/2022",
                    "description": "Sampling test description ",
                    "objective_name": "Next Year Target",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-01-26",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 11,
                    "objective_id": 355,
                    "id": 11,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-01-26T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "testing 34546778",
                    "description": "4wed",
                    "objective_name": "Test objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-02-03",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 20,
                    "objective_id": 348,
                    "id": 26,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-02-03T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "testing date saving - current or -1",
                    "description": "Testing W96",
                    "objective_name": "People Diversity",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-02-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 65,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 71,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-02-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Feb update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Feb",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-03-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 66,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 72,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-03-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Mar update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Mar",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-04-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 67,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 73,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Apr update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Apr",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-05-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 68,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 74,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-05-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "May update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : May",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-06-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 69,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 75,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-06-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Jun update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Jun",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-07-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 70,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 76,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-07-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Jul update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Jul",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                },
                {
                    "schedule_id": 72,
                    "objective_id": 385,
                    "id": 78,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-07-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Jul update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Jul",
                    "objective_name": "25 Jan offer",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-08-24",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 71,
                    "objective_id": 384,
                    "id": 77,
                    "action": null,
                    "event_date": "2022-08-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Aug update schedule",
                    "description": "Update schedule for the Month : Aug",
                    "objective_name": "Date Validation check objective",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-08-29",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 14,
                    "objective_id": 344,
                    "id": 19,
                    "action": "Test solution",
                    "event_date": "2022-08-29T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Testing date issue",
                    "description": "dsfksjdf sdfl sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf ",
                    "objective_name": "Next Year Target",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskDate": "2022-09-29",
            "objectives": [
                {
                    "schedule_id": 16,
                    "objective_id": 344,
                    "id": 21,
                    "action": "Test solution",
                    "event_date": "2022-09-29T18:30:00.000Z",
                    "task_name": "Testing date",
                    "description": "test date description",
                    "objective_name": "Next Year Target",
                    "objective_risk_name": null,
                    "owner": "Self"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want the following response object

```
 [
    { 
        taskDate: "2022-02-21",
        objectives: [
            {
                "objective":"People Diversity",
                "objective_id":348,
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "id":164, 
                        "todoId":109, 
                        "risk_name":null, 
                        "action":null, 
                        "eventDate":"2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z", 
                        "task_name":"Task created 2202022", 
                        "task_description":"Testing task created on 02202022", 
                        "owner":"Self", 
                        "delegate": { 
                            "name":"Alia Bhatt", 
                            "image":"./uploads/1643039740383.jpeg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":164, 
                        "todoId":109, 
                        "risk_name":null, 
                        "action":null, 
                        "eventDate":"2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z", 
                        "task_name":"Task created 2202022", 
                        "task_description":"Testing task created on 02202022", 
                        "owner":"Self", 
                        "delegate": { 
                            "name":"Alia Bhatt", 
                            "image":"./uploads/1643039740383.jpeg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "objective":"People Diversity Demo",
                "objective_id":25,
                "tasks": []
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        taskDate: "2022-02-22",
        objectives: [
            {
                "objective":"People Diversity",
                "objective_id":348,
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "id":164, 
                        "todoId":109, 
                        "risk_name":null, 
                        "action":null, 
                        "eventDate":"2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z", 
                        "task_name":"Task created 2202022", 
                        "task_description":"Testing task created on 02202022", 
                        "owner":"Self", 
                        "delegate": { 
                            "name":"Alia Bhatt", 
                            "image":"./uploads/1643039740383.jpeg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "objective":"People Diversity",
                "objective_id":348,
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "id":164, 
                        "todoId":109, 
                        "risk_name":null, 
                        "action":null, 
                        "eventDate":"2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z", 
                        "task_name":"Task created 2202022", 
                        "task_description":"Testing task created on 02202022", 
                        "owner":"Self", 
                        "delegate": { 
                            "name":"Alia Bhatt", 
                            "image":"./uploads/1643039740383.jpeg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        taskDate: "2022-02-22",
        objectives: [
            {
                "objective":"People Diversity",
                "objective_id":348,
                "tasks": []
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

**Please help to create the required response object**

Comment: your second json object is not valid ?

Comment: no its currect, its required output from the given object

Comment: What language? What have you tried? Do you get the response as an Observable? A promise?

Comment: i am creating an API in nodeJs and front-end developer need that object that i have post in my question

Comment: Finally got the output by self

Answer (score 0):

```
 const mainArr = [];
    // manupluating array
    const taskDate = [];
    for (let e of scheduled) {
      const date = String(e.event_date).split("T")[0];
      const isExist = taskDate.includes(date);
      if (!isExist) {
        taskDate.push(date);
        const newArray = {
          taskDate: e.event_date,
          objectives: [],
        };
        const objectiveInc = [];
        for (let objId of scheduled) {
          const dateObjId = String(objId.event_date).split("T")[0];
          if (dateObjId === date) {
            const isExistObjId = objectiveInc.includes(objId.objective_id);
            if (!isExistObjId) {
              objectiveInc.push(objId.objective_id);
              const objArr = {
                objective: objId.objective_name,
                objective_id: objId.objective_id,
                tasks: [],
              };
              const tIdsInc = [];
              for (let tId of scheduled) {
                const dateTid = String(tId.event_date).split("T")[0];
                if (
                  dateTid === dateObjId &&
                  objId.objective_id === tId.objective_id
                ) {
                  const isExistTId = tIdsInc.includes(tId.id);
                  // console.log("schedule:", userInfo);
                  if (!isExistTId) {
                    let userInfo = await getInfoFromTaskid(tId.schedule_id);
                    tIdsInc.push(objId.id);
                    objArr.tasks.push({
                      id: tId.id,
                      schedule_id: tId.schedule_id,
                      action: tId.action,
                      event_date: tId.event_date,
                      task_name: tId.task_name,
                      description: tId.description,
                      objective_risk_name: tId.objective_risk_name,
                      owner: tId.owner,
                      delegate: {
                        name: userInfo.length > 0 ? userInfo[0]?.full_name : "",
                        image: isFileExist(
                          userInfo.length > 0 ? userInfo[0]?.image : ""
                        ),
                      },
                    });
                    // objArr.tasks.push(tId);
                  }
                }
              }
              newArray.objectives.push(objArr);
            }
          }
        }
        mainArr.push(newArray);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe explain the answer a little? It will help the OP.